# Combine rows from three tables into one for each set of pid (One reference id)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below tables in mysql,

```
tbl_1:
```

[image]

```
 tbl_2:
```

[image]

```
 tbl_3:
```

[image]

From above three tables, am trying to combine the rows for each set of pid into one single table like below :

[image]

So, tbl_3 will have max rows (4), tbl_2 will have upto 3 rows and tbl_1 will have one row for each pid.

Only tbl_1 rows can be redundant, but not tbl_2 and tbl_3.

I cannot use joins, as I do not have any other key to reference, I should use only pid in all these three tables and dump them into single table.
If I use, I will get redundant data of tbl_2 and tbl_3 as well.

For this reason, I used a complex SP, which creates a temporary table for each set of pid and updates it for tbl_2 and tbl_3.
But I was told that it is not the right practice to update row by row rather set based.

How can I achieve required result using mysql query?

**EDIT:
I tried the below so far**

```
create table tbl_1(pid int, loc varchar(100), avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100));
create table tbl_2(soid int,pid int,sid int,name2 varchar(100), nrt2 int);
create table tbl_3(woid int,pid int,wid int,name3 varchar(100), nrt3 int);

create table tbl_sourcef(id int primary key auto_increment,pid int, loc varchar(100), avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100),sid int,nrt2 int,wid int,nrt3 int);
```

After inserting data into above tables

```
insert into tbl_1 values (1000,'Bangalore',30,9,'ABC');

insert into tbl_2 values(0,1000,1,'name1',8);
insert into tbl_2 values(1,1000,8,'name2',5);
insert into tbl_2 values(2,1000,7,'name3',6);

insert into tbl_3 values(0,1000,2,'D1',9);
insert into tbl_3 values(1,1000,1,'D2',2);
insert into tbl_3 values(2,1000,3,'D3',0);
insert into tbl_3 values(3,1000,4,'D4',5);
```

Am using a stored procedure named fupdate()

here is the definition of SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fupdate(
pid int,loc varchar(100),avaId int,xpId int,qf varchar(100)
)
begin
        declare pi int Default 1;
        WHILE pi  <= 10 DO
            insert into tbl_sourcef(pid,loc,avaId,xpId,qf)values(pid,loc,avaId,xpId,qf);
            SET  pi = pi + 1;
        END WHILE;

     begin
              declare i int Default 1 ;
              declare si int default 0;
              declare es int;
              set es=(select count(sid) from tbl_2 where pid=pid);
                WHILE i  <= es DO
                    update tbl_sourcef ff
                    set ff.sid=(select sid from tbl_2 where soid=si and pid=pid),
                        ff.nrt2=(select nrt2 from tbl_2 where soid=si and pid=pid)
                    where id=i and pid=pid;
                    SET  i = i + 1;
                    SET si=si+1;
                END WHILE;
      end;
      begin
              declare wi int Default 1 ;
              declare wii int default 0;
              declare ew int;
              set ew=(select count(wid) from tbl_3 where pid=pid);
                WHILE wi  <= ew DO
                    update tbl_sourcef ff
                    set ff.wid=(select wid from tbl_3 where woid=wii and pid=pid ),
                        ff.nrt3=(select nrt3 from tbl_3 where woid=wii and pid=pid)
                    where id=wi and pid=pid ;
                    SET  wi = wi + 1;
                    SET wii=wii+1;
                END WHILE;
        end;

end
```

Please note that this SP is failing when I use for second set of pid :(..
Not sure if I there is some easy way of achieving the expected result rather using this SP.

This is how am calling my SP -

```
call fupdate(1000,'Bangalore',30,9,'ABC')
```

Comment: post the code what you have tried so far then it will be much more easier

Comment: Sure Mohan,.. let me add the SP

Comment: Added the code, please check it

Comment: what is the output you are expecting from these three tables..procedure is too confusing

Comment: I would like to combine the first three tables into one table (new temporary table is also OK).. It should have the data like I shown in screenshot 4. tbl_3 rows will always have max, tbl_2 will have number of rows less than tbl_3 .. rows from these two tables shouldn't be repeated in final table.. And tbl_1 rows can be repeated. please refer the fourth screenshot I added

Comment: What is the common column other than `pid` in `tbl_2` and `tbl_3` which makes record unique while joining data ..because combination of tbl_2 and tbl_3 always generate 12 record due the same PID values.

Comment: Because if we join 1st record of `tbl_2` with `tbl_3` using PID value then it will automatically joined with remaining records due to the same PID values.

Comment: there is no other common column in tbl_2 and tbl_3 unfortunately.. (they have their own auto incremented keys - but cannot be referenced).. Only column is pid

Comment: Why are you using a sproc?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to combine them into one single table using joins.. so, I used SP to update tbl_2 and tbl_3 rows in the final table..  Is there any other way to achieve the expected result?

Comment: @SathishPanduga if you want we can get the result set like in screen shot 4 but not in your store procedure

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following query to get the result set like in screenshot 4 without using your store procedure:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT COALESCE(tt.pid, ttt.pid) AS pid, tt.sid, tt.name2, 
    ttt.wid, ttt.name3,ttt.nrt3
  FROM tbl_2 tt
  FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_3 ttt
    ON tt.pid = ttt.pid
    AND  tt.soid = ttt.woid 
)
select *
from tbl_1 t
JOIN cte c
  ON t.pid = c.pid;
```